# 60fps and 30fps clips exported into one file?

Tags: framerate, vegas-pro, export, multi-camera

I have two cameras: one films in 30fps and the other in 60fps. These settings cannot be changed (why the manufacturer did that I don't know).

When I export the finished product, which is the better setting to go by? HD 30fps or HD 60fps?

I am using Sony Vegas Pro 13.

Comment: Is the end use web playback?

Comment: @Mulvya Digital playback on an HD TV with 120hz refresh rate.

Comment: Set project to 60 fps and export at 60 fps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Export to 30p. 29.97 to be exact if there is the option. Exporting at 60fps is only going to bloat the file size (twice as many frames) per second-- if it's 60p and not 60i of data to encode.

Secondly, viewers are akin to watching media playback in or around the 24-30fps range. It's what our eyes are used to, so your viewers wont be distracted as to why the 60 fps has less jutter than your 30 fps material.

Lastly, exporting at 30 fps will convert your 60 fps content to 30 fps by dropping out every other frame. Doing the opposite would mean doubling each 30fps content... and it will not look quite the same.

There are filmmakers that have rallied for moving towards a higher frame rate, lower resolution per frame exhibition format. The Hobbit was one of the most recent films (only one I can think of) that was actually screened in what they coined as HFS (High Frames per Second). I saw it in theaters in this format, and to be honest, it didn't feel like film because of it.

Go 30p. 29.97 Progressive.

Answer (score 0):

**Export to 60p for preservation**

You will preserve all the frames and the look of your 60p sources, and the 30p frames will be doubled, but with a decent codec this will likely not affect the size of the file because the encoder will use a "frame-repeat" flag.

**Export to 30p for uniform look**

60p video looks "live", while 30p video looks more "film-like". Combining the two in one video may look jarring to your viewers. Then again, some viewers do not notice differences in frame rates.

**Export to 30p and use 60p for slo-mo**

You can export a 30p project and create true slo-mo from your 60p content, just navigate to clips' properties and set their speed to 0.5 -- no frames lost, and no fake frames added.

As for whether your viewers will be able to watch 60p - yes, they will. Any TV set supports 720p60 and most do support 1080p60. YouTube supports 60p for several years now. If you want to be extra safe, when exporting to 60p use 720 resolution, that is, export to 720p60.